# X509Chain building using a custom certificate store

Tags: c#, security, ssl-certificate, x509

In order to perform SSL certificate validation, I am assigning a callback to `System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback` and then I'm trying to build the X.509 chain on my own to check if the server certificate was issued by a collection of CA's I trust.

I understand I can expand the collection of certificates to be used during chain build (by adding new items to `X509Chain.ChainPolicy.ExtraStore`) - but that is used to trust additional certificates that are not in the local certificate store.

How can I actually **restrict** the chain building to a given store I build programatically myself? I couldn't find a way to use a customized `X509Store` object to be used when calling `X509Chain.Build(X509Certificate2)`.

Comment: What about using Bouncy Castle C# `PkixCertPathBuilder` API?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no way to restrict a set of trusted root (trusted anchors) in .NET. However, you can call native (C++-like) CryptoAPI functions via interop.

Basically, you will need to use [CertCreateCertificateChainEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376032(v=vs.85).aspx) function and use customized input chaining engine configuration structure: [CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa377184(v=vs.85).aspx).

You will need to create a virtual (without explicit registration in Windows Certificate Store) store, add a set of trusted certificates of your choice. Get store handle/pointer and pass it in the `hRestrictedRoot` parameter in the `CERT_CHAIN_ENGINE_CONFIG` object. In this case, default root store will not be used. The function returns a handle to `HCERTCHAINENGINE` which can be used then in [CertGetCertificateChain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376078(v=vs.85).aspx) function call (where actual chain validation occurs).

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to restrict (vs "replace") the trust list, that's pretty easy, just take the chain provided in the callback and see if it's conforming.

```
HashSet<X509Certificate2> s_allowedRoots = new HashSet<X509Certificate2>
{
    trustedCertA,
    trustedCertB,
    ...
};

...

// In your callback

if (errors != SslPolicyErrors.None)
{
    return false;
}

X509Certificate2 chainRoot = chain.ChainElements[chain.ChainElements.Count - 1].Certificate;

return s_allowedRoots.Contains(chainRoot);
```

Comment: I had the idea of using that, but that does not help in having full control over the certificates used in the chain building process.

Comment: Equality for X509Certificate2 is defined as having the same issuer and serial number. Because of this, the .NET documentation advises against using .Equals (or methods that rely on it, such as .Contains) for security purposes. If you want to use a HashSet, it should be a HashSet of certificate Thumbprints or RawData hashes.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Now you can use X509chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore to add your root certificate and use it to build chain.

```
var chain = new X509Chain();
        chain.ChainPolicy.RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck;
        chain.ChainPolicy.TrustMode = X509ChainTrustMode.CustomRootTrust;
        chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Clear();
        chain.ChainPolicy.CustomTrustStore.Add(yourRootCertificate);
        chain.Build(yourCert);
```